# RabbitMQ pod is crashing unexpectedly

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq

I have a pod running RabbitMQ. Below is the deployment manifest:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-rabbitmq
spec:
  selector:
    app: service-rabbitmq
  ports:
    - port: 5672
      targetPort: 5672
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deployment-rabbitmq
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: deployment-rabbitmq
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: deployment-rabbitmq
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: rabbitmq
          image: rabbitmq:latest
          volumeMounts:
            - name: rabbitmq-data-volume
              mountPath: /var/lib/rabbitmq
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 250m
              memory: 128Mi
            limits:
              cpu: 750m
              memory: 256Mi
      volumes:
        - name: rabbitmq-data-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: rabbitmq-pvc
```

When I deploy it in my local cluster, I see the pod running for a while and then crashing afterwards. So basically it goes under crash-loop. Following is the logs I got from the pod:

```
$ kubectl logs deployment-rabbitmq-649b8479dc-kt9s4
2021-10-14 06:46:36.182390+00:00 [info] <0.222.0> Feature flags: list of feature flags found:
2021-10-14 06:46:36.221717+00:00 [info] <0.222.0> Feature flags:   [ ] implicit_default_bindings
2021-10-14 06:46:36.221768+00:00 [info] <0.222.0> Feature flags:   [ ] maintenance_mode_status
2021-10-14 06:46:36.221792+00:00 [info] <0.222.0> Feature flags:   [ ] quorum_queue
2021-10-14 06:46:36.221813+00:00 [info] <0.222.0> Feature flags:   [ ] stream_queue
2021-10-14 06:46:36.221916+00:00 [info] <0.222.0> Feature flags:   [ ] user_limits
2021-10-14 06:46:36.221933+00:00 [info] <0.222.0> Feature flags:   [ ] virtual_host_metadata
2021-10-14 06:46:36.221953+00:00 [info] <0.222.0> Feature flags: feature flag states written to disk: yes
2021-10-14 06:46:37.018537+00:00 [noti] <0.44.0> Application syslog exited with reason: stopped
2021-10-14 06:46:37.018646+00:00 [noti] <0.222.0> Logging: switching to configured handler(s); following messages may not be visible in this log output
2021-10-14 06:46:37.045601+00:00 [noti] <0.222.0> Logging: configured log handlers are now ACTIVE
2021-10-14 06:46:37.635024+00:00 [info] <0.222.0> ra: starting system quorum_queues
2021-10-14 06:46:37.635139+00:00 [info] <0.222.0> starting Ra system: quorum_queues in directory: /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@deployment-rabbitmq-649b8479dc-kt9s4/quorum/rabbit@deployment-rabbitmq-649b8479dc-kt9s4
2021-10-14 06:46:37.849041+00:00 [info] <0.259.0> ra: meta data store initialised for system quorum_queues. 0 record(s) recovered
2021-10-14 06:46:37.877504+00:00 [noti] <0.264.0> WAL: ra_log_wal init, open tbls: ra_log_open_mem_tables, closed tbls: ra_log_closed_mem_tables
```

This log isn't helpful too much, I can't find any error message from here. The only useful line here could be `Application syslog exited with reason: stopped`, only but it's not as far as I understand. The event log isn't helpful too:

```
$ kubectl describe pods deployment-rabbitmq-649b8479dc-kt9s4
Name:         deployment-rabbitmq-649b8479dc-kt9s4
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         docker-desktop/192.168.65.4
Start Time:   Thu, 14 Oct 2021 12:45:03 +0600
Labels:       app=deployment-rabbitmq
              pod-template-hash=649b8479dc
              skaffold.dev/run-id=7af5e1bb-e0c8-4021-a8a0-0c8bf43630b6
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           10.1.5.138
IPs:
  IP:           10.1.5.138
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/deployment-rabbitmq-649b8479dc
Containers:
  rabbitmq:
    Container ID:   docker://de309f94163c071afb38fb8743d106923b6bda27325287e82bc274e362f1f3be
    Image:          rabbitmq:latest
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://rabbitmq@sha256:d8efe7b818e66a13fdc6fdb84cf527984fb7d73f52466833a20e9ec298ed4df4
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       OOMKilled
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Thu, 14 Oct 2021 13:56:29 +0600
      Finished:     Thu, 14 Oct 2021 13:56:39 +0600
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  18
    Limits:
      cpu:     750m
      memory:  256Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:        250m
      memory:     128Mi
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/lib/rabbitmq from rabbitmq-data-volume (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-9shdv (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  rabbitmq-data-volume:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  rabbitmq-pvc
    ReadOnly:   false
  kube-api-access-9shdv:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason   Age                    From     Message
  ----     ------   ----                   ----     -------
  Normal   Pulled   23m (x6 over 50m)      kubelet  (combined from similar events): Successfully pulled image "rabbitmq:latest" in 4.267310231s
  Normal   Pulling  18m (x16 over 73m)     kubelet  Pulling image "rabbitmq:latest"
  Warning  BackOff  3m45s (x307 over 73m)  kubelet  Back-off restarting failed container
```

What could be the reason for this crash-loop?

> **NOTE:** `rabbitmq-pvc` is successfully bound. No issue there.

### Update:

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58610625/11317272) indicates that RabbitMQ should be deployed as **StatefulSet**. So I adjusted the manifest like so:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-rabbitmq
spec:
  selector:
    app: service-rabbitmq
  ports:
    - name: rabbitmq-amqp
      port: 5672
    - name: rabbitmq-http
      port: 15672
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: statefulset-rabbitmq
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: statefulset-rabbitmq
  serviceName: service-rabbitmq
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: statefulset-rabbitmq
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: rabbitmq
          image: rabbitmq:latest
          volumeMounts:
            - name: rabbitmq-data-volume
              mountPath: /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 250m
              memory: 128Mi
            limits:
              cpu: 750m
              memory: 256Mi
      volumes:
        - name: rabbitmq-data-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: rabbitmq-pvc
```

The pod still undergoes crash-loop, but the logs are slightly different.

```
$ kubectl logs statefulset-rabbitmq-0
2021-10-14 09:38:26.138224+00:00 [info] <0.222.0> Feature flags: list of feature flags found:
2021-10-14 09:38:26.158953+00:00 [info] <0.222.0> Feature flags:   [x] implicit_default_bindings
2021-10-14 09:38:26.159015+00:00 [info] <0.222.0> Feature flags:   [x] maintenance_mode_status
2021-10-14 09:38:26.159037+00:00 [info] <0.222.0> Feature flags:   [x] quorum_queue
2021-10-14 09:38:26.159078+00:00 [info] <0.222.0> Feature flags:   [x] stream_queue
2021-10-14 09:38:26.159183+00:00 [info] <0.222.0> Feature flags:   [x] user_limits
2021-10-14 09:38:26.159236+00:00 [info] <0.222.0> Feature flags:   [x] virtual_host_metadata
2021-10-14 09:38:26.159270+00:00 [info] <0.222.0> Feature flags: feature flag states written to disk: yes
2021-10-14 09:38:26.830814+00:00 [noti] <0.44.0> Application syslog exited with reason: stopped
2021-10-14 09:38:26.830925+00:00 [noti] <0.222.0> Logging: switching to configured handler(s); following messages may not be visible in this log output
2021-10-14 09:38:26.852048+00:00 [noti] <0.222.0> Logging: configured log handlers are now ACTIVE
2021-10-14 09:38:33.754355+00:00 [info] <0.222.0> ra: starting system quorum_queues
2021-10-14 09:38:33.754526+00:00 [info] <0.222.0> starting Ra system: quorum_queues in directory: /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@statefulset-rabbitmq-0/quorum/rabbit@statefulset-rabbitmq-0
2021-10-14 09:38:33.760365+00:00 [info] <0.290.0> ra: meta data store initialised for system quorum_queues. 0 record(s) recovered
2021-10-14 09:38:33.761023+00:00 [noti] <0.302.0> WAL: ra_log_wal init, open tbls: ra_log_open_mem_tables, closed tbls: ra_log_closed_mem_tables
```

The feature flags are now marked as it's seen. No other notable changes. So I still need help.

### ! New Issue !

Head over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69574698/11317272).

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud providor? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Client: 1.22. Server: 1.21. Cluster is in my local machine, running Windows 10 Pro and WSL2 (Debian). Just copy the above manifest and apply it to the cluster. Then watch the pod. You'll see **Running**-**OOMKilled**-**CrashLoopBackOff** states cycling through.

Comment: for the new issue, please create separate question.

Comment: Done. Feel free to check it out. Link in the question above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pod gets oomkilled (last state, reason) and you need to assign more resources (memory) to the pod.

Comment: How much resources should I allocate? Right now it's set to `250m` - `750m` for CPU and `128Mi` - `256Mi` for RAM. I couldn't find any recommended values anywhere.

Comment: Try doubling the values. A rabbitmq normally requires 256 mb but it seems that it is to less in your case.

Comment: An issue, sir, with the pod. Now I adjusted the resources and it's successfully running now, I'm having another issue. I've edited the original question, and now I'm waiting for you to edit your answer by solving the issue I've put. Thanks in advance - I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Ask a new question please.. Do not change or extend your question if it is answered

Comment: I thought it's related, so I extended. Well, I'll drop a new question then.